# Fast way to save Image Files Python

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have a folder of 10 000 images and I am iterating one by one in a for loop and every time after processing I am saving the modified image in a file. Problem with the execution is it is taking long time to process even 500 images and I see CPU Usage in Windows Task Manager are going up to 80%.

How to speed up below code? Anything like save all processed image in memory and write it at single shot?

```
    from PIL import Image
    from resizeimage import resizeimage
    for imgnm in range(0, samples):
        start = time.time()
        filename=filenames[imgnm]
        img = Image.open(os.path.join(imagedir,filename))
        img=resizeimage.resize_crop(img, [700, 700])
        (img.resize((700,700),Image.ANTIALIAS)).save(os.path.join(subdir,filename),quality=40)
        img.close()
```

Comment: Easiest speedup I can think of is to try and run the script for different images in parallel (by running several processes for different images at the same time or running in different threads)

Comment: I think your problem is io bound, so your cpu can work just with 80%. You should use a faster storage like a ssd

Comment: You are probably hitting an IO-snag here. Use an SSD for performant read/writes. Before we Guess - you should measure and optimize where needed...

Comment: considering you are saving pics that are 700x700, then the io bound may not be an issue
but my question is - do you have to use python in this case? can't you use sth faster like irfanview's batch processing?

Comment: If you are looking for performance... sequential, unparallelised, Python code on Windows is missing just about every box you could check. `pyvips` is just about your only hope.

Comment: Are you sure it's saving and not the resize that consumes all the CPU?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How to speed up below code?

1. Use latest Pillow version
2. Use Pillow-SIMD instead (drop-in replacement for CPUs with at least SSE4)
3. Use the less expensive filter for resizing: `Image.BICUBIC` or even `Image.BILINEAR`
4. Do one resize and one crop (before resize) instead of using both `resizeimage` and `img.resize`.
5. Save images to the fast format. Different formats operate at a different speed. PNG in the slowest one, while JPEG and TIFF are the fastest.

Comment: Thanks! Great suggestions.